# How to add scroll bar for React bootstrap DropDown?

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am using react bootstrap dropdown, [from here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/)

When the items in my drop down list are many, the list gets overflown vertically which is not responsive as shown in the snapshot [image]
I want to add a scroll bar to it but am not able to. Please help.

This is my sample code

```
            <DropdownButton
                id="dropdown-basic-button"
                title={this.props.passenger.seatNumber}
                onSelect={(evt) => this.handleSeatSelection(evt)}
                variant="info"
              >
                {this.state.availableSeatNumbers.map((seatNumber) => (
                  <Dropdown.Item key={seatNumber} eventKey={seatNumber}>
                    {seatNumber}
                  </Dropdown.Item>
                ))}
              </DropdownButton>
```

Comment: I believe that it's the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/q/45380397/863110

Comment: Thanks for finding it out buddy. I voted my question to be duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply give a fixed height to your dropdown menu class and set the overflow-y to scroll as written below

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```